# Bracket evaluation

Tags: expression

Which should be evaluated first, x=1 or x=2?

In this case:
Y=(x*(x=1))/(x+(x=2))

And in this case:
Y=(6+(x-(x=1))/(4+(9-(x*(x=2))))

...for example.

I knocked together a very rough guess at an expression evaluator a while back.  I plumped for simple left to right precedence in bracket evaluation (obviously still depth first for each bracket set), but the question of which bracket set ought to be evaluated first puzzles me.  The deepest set first or stick with l to r precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your choice.  From this Wikipedia Article "[Order of Operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)":

```
Many programming languages use precedence levels that conform to the order 
commonly used in mathematics, though some, such as APL and Smalltalk, have
no operator precedence rules (in APL evaluation is strictly right to left,
in Smalltalk it's strictly left to right).
```

Comment: Thanks... I suppose I was mostly looking for a mathematical answer, though the phrase 'commonly used in' still leaves that door open too I guess.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day it completly up to you how to implement it.
But from my experiencece most popular languages are using left to right. Very obvious example would be evaluation of logical expressions like:

```
if (obj != null && obj.propertyA == "a")
```

in case of right to left you would have had an exception